# Why doesn't my Windows username work when I deploy my Site to IIS on my home computer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a site that I have developed and deployed to an IIS server at work fine. However, when I try to do the same at home, I am unable to connect properly. It doesn't allow me to go through and chrome keeps showing a popup to put my username and password in which I believe I've done properly. In the office, we are using a network and have AD on. I believe  it might have something to do with this but I"m not entirely sure.

I am not sure what settings I am missing that will allow me to connect to my site that I've deployed at home?

I can run through the site fine with Visual Studio if I use debug mode.

I am running Windows Authentication and IIS 6.2.

What am I missing with my settings or configuration ?

Comment: is your application trying to connect to any database?

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh Yes, it will be tryign to connect to a database.

Comment: Please check whether the account you have used to connect to DB is the same as your home AD account...

Comment: What host name do you use locally? Does it work when using `localhost`. Also there is no such thing as `IIS 6.2` which version of Windows are you using?